# How to resolve conflict between portage and entropy

Tags: package-management, gentoo, portage

I have recently installed a fresh Sabayon 7 + KDE distribution. Now I am installing some software using portage. I have typed "emerge thunderbird", however the installation failed because of conflict. What I see is, that installing the package "pinentry" from portage would overwrite some files from package "pinentry-base" that is managed by entropy. How can I resolve this conflict? Here is the error message:

```
* Messages for package app-crypt/pinentry-0.8.1:

 * This package will overwrite one or more files that may belong to other
 * packages (see list below). You can use a command such as `portageq
 * owners / <filename>` to identify the installed package that owns a
 * file. If portageq reports that only one package owns a file then do
 * NOT file a bug report. A bug report is only useful if it identifies at
 * least two or more packages that are known to install the same file(s).
 * If a collision occurs and you can not explain where the file came from
 * then you should simply ignore the collision since there is not enough
 * information to determine if a real problem exists. Please do NOT file
 * a bug report at http://bugs.gentoo.org unless you report exactly which
 * two packages install the same file(s). Once again, please do NOT file
 * a bug report unless you have completely understood the above message.
 * 
 * Detected file collision(s):
 * 
 *      /usr/share/info/pinentry.info.bz2
 *      /usr/bin/pinentry-qt4
 *      /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
 * 
 * Searching all installed packages for file collisions...
 * 
 * Press Ctrl-C to Stop
 * 
 * app-crypt/pinentry-qt4-0.8.1-r1
 *      /usr/bin/pinentry-qt4
 * 
 * app-crypt/pinentry-base-0.8.1
 *      /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
 *      /usr/share/info/pinentry.info.bz2
 * 
 * Package 'app-crypt/pinentry-0.8.1' NOT merged due to file collisions.
 * If necessary, refer to your elog messages for the whole content of the
 * above message.
```

and the command portageq owners / /usr/share/info/pinentry.info.bz2 says:

```
app-crypt/pinentry-base-0.8.1
        /usr/share/info/pinentry.info.bz2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixing `portage` with `entropy` leads to problems. They are a bit different methods of managing your system packages and unfortunately do not always cooperate nicely. I had similar problems some time ago and finally ended up turning my *Sabayon* entirely into *Gentoo*, which I had already felt comfortable with. If you really want to go on mixing `entropy` with `portage`, [the Sabayon wiki](http://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=HOWTO:_Fix_what_portage_breaks_(minimize_portage_use_by_moving_packges_back_to_entropy).) might be helpful to you.

In this particular case, the best solution would be to first remove `app-crypt/pinentry-qt4` and `app-crypt/pinentry-base` (via entropy) and then retry emerging `thunderbird`.

In other cases, especially when there are no file owners found, you might use the `COLLISION_IGNORE` variable to force emerging of a package despite collisions. But do so **with extreme caution**, as you may break your system, overwriting things that other packages depend on. The variable needs to indicate, what part of system directory tree should be *unprotected*, so in your case it would be enough to run `COLLISION_IGNORE="/usr" emerge -1 app-crypt/pinentry` (the `-1` is there to prevent `pinentry` from landing in your `world` file.